# CakePHP component or another controller class?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

To use same logic between controller classes we can create [components](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html). But I wonder what are the advantages of components to a custom class?

We can construct an instance of a controller class within another class. So we can use same logic with `$MyOtherController->myAction` rather than `$this->MyComponent->myAction`.
Can you compare them? Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP components and behaviors are basically applications of the decorator pattern. While you might think you could achieve the same results by subclassing the `AppController` class, if you were to consider all the different combinations that components might be used in, this would require you creating an unwieldy amount of subclasses to achieve the same results as just a handful of components. In contrast, you can mix and match components/behaviors at will through dependency injection.

Lets say you currently have 3 controller subclasses:

1. `MultiStepController`
2. `SecurityController`
3. `MultiStepSecurityController`

If you were to come up with a new type of controller you wanted to add, then you'd have to create 4 new controller subclasses:

1. `FooMultiStepController`
2. `FooSecurityController`
3. `FooMultiStepSecurityController`
4. `FooController`

That's a lot of redundant code and unnecessary work compared to just adding `'Foo'` to the `$components` variable of any controller you wanted to use the component in.

So from the perspective of maintainability and code reuse, components are a far better solution in most cases than subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

The docs about components-class:

> Base class for an individual Component. Components provide reusable bits of controller logic that can be composed into a controller. Components also provide request life-cycle callbacks for injecting logic at specific points.
>
> Components can provide several callbacks that are fired at various stages of the request cycle. The available callbacks are:
>
> - initialize() - Fired before the controller's beforeFilter method.
> - startup() - Fired after the controller's beforeFilter method.
> - beforeRender() - Fired before the view + layout are rendered.
> - shutdown() - Fired after the action is complete and the view has been rendered but before Controller::afterFilter().
> - beforeRedirect() - Fired before a redirect() is done.

You can of course achieve all this with custom classes (it's still just PHP). Also re-using a component in another app later might be much easier than re-using a custom class.

See [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) or the (often very useful!) [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/component) for more information.